# Postgres High Cpu for every run until I run analyze

Tags: postgresql

I have a batch job that processes about 50k rows a day.. the query that is executed looks like the following. The tables are partitioned!

```
select
    *
from
    billing abstractbi0_
inner join sale sale1_ on abstractbi0_.sale_billing_date = sale1_.billing_date
    and abstractbi0_.sale_id = sale1_.id
where
    abstractbi0_.dtype in ('INVOICE_CORRECTED_BEFORE_BILLING', 'INVOICE', 'GOODWILL', 'REFUND', 'ZERO_SUM')
    and sale1_.proposal_id = '47037059-d231-40d9-a0f5-242577596b5c'
    and abstractbi0_.billing_date = '2022-09-27'
    and sale1_.billing_date = '2022-09-27';
```

Every time when the batch job starts the cpu gets to 100% and the performance is very bad. When I run analyze during the high cpu phase the performance get 20x better.

the execution plan before running analyze...

```
Nested Loop  (cost=0.85..14.67 rows=1 width=574)
  Join Filter: (abstractbi0_.sale_id = sale1_.id)
  ->  Index Scan using billing_p2022_09_sale_billing_date_sale_id_idx on billing_p2022_09 abstractbi0_  (cost=0.43..8.45 rows=1 width=467)
        Index Cond: (sale_billing_date = '2022-09-27'::date)
        Filter: ((billing_date = '2022-09-27'::date) AND ((dtype)::text = ANY ('{INVOICE_CORRECTED_BEFORE_BILLING,INVOICE,GOODWILL,REFUND,ZERO_SUM}'::text[])))
  ->  Index Scan using sale_p2022_09_pkey on sale_p2022_09 sale1_  (cost=0.43..6.20 rows=1 width=107)
        Index Cond: (billing_date = '2022-09-27'::date)
        Filter: (proposal_id = '47037059-d231-40d9-a0f5-242577596b5c'::uuid)
```

and after analyze....

```
Nested Loop  (cost=0.85..16.91 rows=1 width=1084)
  ->  Index Scan using sale_p2022_09_billing_date_proposal_id_idx on sale_p2022_09 sale1_  (cost=0.43..8.45 rows=1 width=107)
        Index Cond: ((billing_date = '2022-09-27'::date) AND (proposal_id = '47037059-d231-40d9-a0f5-242577596b5c'::uuid))
  ->  Index Scan using billing_p2022_09_sale_billing_date_sale_id_billing_date_dty_idx on billing_p2022_09 abstractbi0_  (cost=0.43..8.46 rows=1 width=977)
        Index Cond: ((sale_billing_date = '2022-09-27'::date) AND (sale_id = sale1_.id) AND (billing_date = '2022-09-27'::date))
        Filter: ((dtype)::text = ANY ('{INVOICE_CORRECTED_BEFORE_BILLING,INVOICE,GOODWILL,REFUND,ZERO_SUM}'::text[]))
```

the second plan does not cause 100% cpu and is about 20x faster than the first one.
But the next day the bad plan is back in place and I see 100% cpu again...

I tried to run analyze periodically (every day) because of my partitioned tables. According to the documentation autovacuum does not support partitioned tables.
My tries...

1. just autovacuum --> does not work
2. periodic vacuum analyze with autovacuum --> does not work
3. periodic vacuum analyze without autovacuum --> does not work.

I see only one option now... to increase one of the cpu_*_cost factors to force the planner to prefer the second execution plan. But I am a bit scared of doing that, because it would affect all plans..
Any other ideas?
I use spring/jpa the query is generated...

Comment: The execution plans generated using `explain (analyze, buffers)` would be interesting.

Comment: I think it would be sufficient to have good statistics on the individual partition tables. Perhaps tuning autoanalyze to run more often would be enough. Alternatively, you could run an explicit `ANALYZE` during bulk loading at certain times. Finally, you can try to rewrite the query to force the planner's hand, but I didn't look into that.

Comment: Custom statistics might also help, but first you have to understand why this issue pops up. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createstatistics.html

Comment: I am pretty sure that the trouble occurs because you are using UUID (or GUID) as a primary key of your table which is a bad practice for performances... By the fact that UUID/GUID are generated in a randomized way, that disrupt the indexes organisation and statistics...

Comment: If "periodic vacuum analyze without autovacuum" does not work, then what is the thing that does work?

Comment: What is the partitioning scheme?

Comment: Once you start populating dates that never used to be populated, the stats will obviously be out of date.  But without EXPLAIN ANALYZE, we can't tell how out they are, or on which table.

Answer (score 1):

The solution....
Giving my own solution I found here - maybe helpful for others.

What happens

1.) The database is partitioned, so new data (for each month) goes to a new partition.

2.) If the partition is empty or nearly empty the statistics reflects that it is more performant to load the few records into memory than using an index and then in a second fetch load the data.

3.) The partition get filled with lots of data. --> Now the statistics are outdated and the planner still preferre to load all data to memory and filter in memory --> high cpu occures.
after a second run of analyze the planner now uses the index.

So It is pretty important to know, that using partitioned tables in postgres, means to be very careful when to run analyze.
the auto-analyze on unpartitioned tables does update the stats automatically after a certain number of inserted rows on an empty table.

So my solution is after the batch begins to run, and it started to fill a new (empty) partition - i manually start analyze after a few minutes to update the stats. Not pretty smart, but solves the problem